# There is no pod with name "cluster-autoscaler-xxx" in AKS cluster with enabled cluster autoscale

Tags: kubernetes, azure, autoscaler

I enabled cluster autoscale in 2 node pools of my AKS cluster (using Azure Portal). It works well.
But I check running pods in kube-system namespace and there is no pod with name "cluster-autoscaler".
How does cluster autoscaler work in AKS cluster?
As my understanding, it should deploy a pod with name "cluster-autoscaler-XXX" in kube-system namespace.
Please help me to understand it.